# Redux router pushState function not triggering URL change

Tags: redux-router

I have followed the example [here](https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example) to try and create a basic authenticated area
for my app, which is a solution I really like in principle. Here is my `index.js`:

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRedirect to="authenticated" />
          <Route path="setup" component={SetupJourney} >
            <Route path="details" component={Details}/>
            <Route path="account" component={AccountType}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="authenticated" component={requireAuthentication(secretPage)} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and then here's my `AuthenticatedComponent` higher-order component to handle redirects:

```
export function requireAuthentication(Component) {

class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.checkAuth();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.checkAuth();
    }

    checkAuth() {
        if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.dispatch(pushState(null, '/setup/details', ''));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.isAuthenticated === true
                    ? <Component {...this.props}/>
                    : null
                }
            </div>
        )

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.get('user').get('isAuthenticated')
});

return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedComponent);

}
```

I've been playing about with this for ages and I cannot get the component to redirect. In Redux dev tools I can see the `@@reduxReactRouter/historyAPI` action has fired, but the URL doesn't change. All the relevant props/state etc seem to be in place too...is there something I've missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, I eventually resolved this and there were a few problems. Firstly, pushState is only for use with browserHistory, so I needed to switch from hashHistory.

After this the pushState still did not work. This can [apparently happen](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router/issues/191) when middleware is specified in the wrong order. I restructured my `index.js` to follow the pattern in Redux's [real world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world), and everything eventually worked.

The key bit is I now have a `store.js` file that looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reducer, { INITIAL_STATE } from '../reducers/reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({reducer, routing: routerReducer});
const composeEnhancers =
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
typeof window === 'object' &&
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
  }) : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(browserHistory))
);

const initialState = {'reducer': INITIAL_STATE};

export default function configureStore() {
  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
}
```